# How to full screen video from webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-fullscreen

Here is my code. I have built webview for youtube and using WebChromClient tried to add full screen feature on app. But when clicked on fullscreen it gives blank screen and auido is played in back ground.

**MainAvtivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public WebView mywebview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mywebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_webview);

    WebSettings webSettings =mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new CrmClient());
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mywebview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");

}



class CrmClient extends WebChromeClient{

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        super.onHideCustomView();
    }
}




@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mywebview != null) {
        mywebview.onPause();
        mywebview.pauseTimers();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mywebview != null){
        mywebview.onResume();
        mywebview.resumeTimers();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mywebview.canGoBack())
        mywebview.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**Activity_main.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_webview" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    </FrameLayout>
</WebView>
```

**AndroidMainFest.XML**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"> 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Don't know if helps, in an old project (about 3 years from now) I found too problematic to lay on webviews to show youtube videos. Solved all my problems using YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi, even full screen works like a charm. It was just importing via gradle or putting a **jar library** on the project and use the methods. I used via .jar : `compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar') ` on my build module. Note: as all other google APIs, you have to be registered on youtube to have this running on your app. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You for your feedback. But I want to make this application without using YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi. Here I get the full-screen option on my WebView when the video is played but when I click on the full-screen option it gives me white screen and audio is still playing in the background.

Comment: Well, good luck. I still recommend you lay on google api to do this. There are many thousands of android devices/systems running out there, each one with its own singularity. Trust me: even google can't handle it all, what to say about us, poor developers, and our "independent" endeavors... One thing you can be sure: this is a device/system matter. If you try your app in 5 only devices, or even same devices with different android api flavors, you will be surprised how things run different each one - even in emus you will find the same. With google's api this can be, at least a little, reduced.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public WebView mywebview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mywebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_webview);

    WebSettings webSettings =mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mywebview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");

 mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onShowCustomView(View view,
                                         WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {

                if (mCustomView != null) {
                    onHideCustomView();
                    return;
                }

                mCustomView = view;
                mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
                mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();

                mCustomViewCallback = callback;

                FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
                decor.addView(mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


              getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onHideCustomView() {
                // 1. Remove the custom view
                FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
                decor.removeView(mCustomView);
                mCustomView = null;

                // 2. Restore the state to it's original form
                getWindow().getDecorView()
                        .setSystemUiVisibility(mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
                setRequestedOrientation(mOriginalOrientation);

                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
                mCustomViewCallback = null;

            }


        });


}
```

and add this

```
private View mCustomView;
    private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;
    private int mOriginalOrientation;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
    protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {

    private View mCustomView;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
    protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
    private int mOriginalOrientation;
    private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

    MyChrome() {}

    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster()
    {
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
    }

    public void onHideCustomView()
    {
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
        this.mCustomView = null;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
        setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
        this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
    }

    public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
    {
        if (this.mCustomView != null)
        {
            onHideCustomView();
            return;
        }
        this.mCustomView = paramView;
        this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846);
    }
}
```

and add this code

```
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());
```

Comment: What is 2130837573 ?